# javascript dropdowns and functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm a beginner in web delpmnt. I need to pass id of a dropdown(html.dropdown) for a javascript function(OpenPopupForSelectedFilters), but what I tried is not working.Funtion is not receiving correct id. Let me know the correct way

My code:

```
<tr>
    @for (var i = 0; i < (@ViewData["AdditionalMaster"] as List<SelectListItem>).Count; i++)
    {
        var item = (@ViewData["AdditionalMaster"] as List<SelectListItem>)[i];
        <tr>   
            <td class="formLabel" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 50px">
                <label>@item.Text</label>
            </td>
            <td class="appliedFilter formField" style="text-align: left; width: 300px; padding-right: 50px">
                @Html.DropDownList("AdditionalMaster" + @item.Value, null, null, new { @Id ="Role"+(@item.Text).Replace(" ",""), @class = "dropdownStyle multiselect ", @multiple = "multiple", @Style = " width:275px;display:none" })
                <a href="javascript:OnClick=OpenPopupForSelectedFilters('Role'+@item.Text.ToString());"style="width: 20px; height: 13px" title="Show Selected Role">
```

JavaScript function:

```
OpenPopupForSelectedFilters = function (val) { debugger;
    var id = '#' + val;
    var ddlText = $(id).multiselect("getChecked").map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    if (ddlText.length == 0)
        document.getElementById('seldFitlers').innerText = "No record(s)";
    else
        document.getElementById('seldFitlers').innerText = $.map($(id + ' :selected'), function (e) { return $(e).text(); }).join('\n');

    $("#dv_forSeldFilters").dialog({ title: 'Selected record(s)' });
    $('#dv_forSeldFilters').dialog('open');
    $('#dv_forSeldFilters').scrollTop(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following line:

```
<a href="javascript:OnClick=OpenPopupForSelectedFilters('Role'+@item.Text.ToString());"
```

You need to encase the @item.Text.ToString() in quotes and remove the "OnClick=" like so:

```
<a href="javascript:OpenPopupForSelectedFilters('Role'+'@item.Text.ToString()');"
```

The reason you need to do this is that the ASP.NET MVC rendering engine will evaluate @item.Text.ToString() to a text literal, not a string. This means in your version it will end up looking like this:

```
<a href="javascript:OpenPopupForSelectedFilters('Role'+MyRole);"
```

Rather than what you're wanting which is this:

```
<a href="javascript:OpenPopupForSelectedFilters('Role'+'MyRole');"
```

Removing the "OnClick=" is more just because it's not necessary.

Comment: If you could mark this as the answer that would be great. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

if the dropdown `id` is `"Role"+(@item.Text).Replace(" ","")`

then you can render the anchor as

```
<a href="javascript:OpenPopupForSelectedFilters('Role@(item.Text.Replace(" ",""))')"></a>
```

there is no need for the `+` and you are removing spaces in the dropdown `id` above.